# How to configure Kubernetics dashboard to access through SSO like Gmail account

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, devops, kubernetes-dashboard

We have a requirement to enable SSO for kubernetics dashboard like Gmail account to login in kubernetics and access dashboard and access label also set on individual accounts .

Comment: SSO like when enter Kubernetics url it will redirect to some gmail account and then which check the credential and accept the token header and as the token access it will redirect to kubernetics dashboard .

Comment: this article look very promising: https://thenewstack.io/single-sign-on-for-kubernetes-dashboard-experience/

Comment: Best way is probably to add an authentication proxy in front of the dashboard